# Sending Jquery UI slider values to database

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-slider

I have a ui slider element that I am using to let people rate a product, the purpose is to have this slider along with a button to insert the value into a MySQL table (sort of voting)

my slider looks like

```
$("#slider-range-max4").slider({
                range: "max",
                min: 1,
                max: 10,
                value: 0,
                slide: function (event, ui) {
                    $("#slider-range-max-amount4").text(ui.value);
                }
            });

            $("#slider-range-max-amount1").text($("#slider-range-max1").slider("value"));
```

How can I use a button to send the value selected by the user to mysql, do I have to embed the code into a form ?

Thanks

Comment: But how that's the thing :) Am a bit lost

Comment: you are using Ranged with fixed maximum.right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use ajax like bellow and send the value to php

```
$(function() {
$( "#slider-range-max" ).slider({
range: "max",
min: 1,
max: 10,
value: 2,
slide: function( event, ui ) {
$( "#amount" ).val( ui.value );
}
});
$( "#amount" ).val( $( "#slider-range-max" ).slider( "value" ) );

    $.ajax({

        type:"POST",
        url:"your.php",
        data:"vote="+$( "#slider-range-max" ).slider( "value" ),
        success:function(response){
        alert(voted);

       } 

    })
});
```

In PHP

```
<?php

$vote="";

if(isset($_POST['vote'])){$vote=$_POST['vote']}

//now do your job with MySql here
?>
```