# How to make this form get the value outputted by jQuery slider?

Tags: php, jquery, forms, user-interface

My problem is that I have found a jQuery UI slider which outputs a number however I cannot seem to find a way to get the PHP file to get the slider value when I submit the form. How can I do this?

Below I have inserted how the PHP file gets the other form elements and also the code for the slider.

jQuery Slider UI

```
<input type="text" data-slider="true" data-slider-range="1,10" data-slider-step="1" name="slidervalue" data-slider-snap="true">
         <script>
      $("[data-slider]")
        .each(function () {
          var input = $(this);
          $("<span>")
            .addClass("output")
            .insertAfter($(this));
        })
        .bind("slider:ready slider:changed", function (event, data) {
          $(this)
            .nextAll(".output:first")
              .html(data.value.toFixed(0));
        });
      </script>
```

PHP Form Submitter

```
$email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";
```

Comment: where is the part in which you are sending the values to the PHP page ?

Comment: The input code line above is where the user would select the value to send to the PHP page.

Comment: See if this answer helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17096883/sending-jquery-ui-slider-values-to-database It would be better if you send your slider values to php via an AJAX request.

Answer (score 0):

Take value of the slider (data.value.toFixed(0)) and insert it into a hidden field inside the form you are working with.

Comment: Sorry I'm completely new to this, how would I do that?